# Jquery sliding drawer with overhang

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

I'm creating a toggling menu using JQuery slide effect. I am trying to make the collapse menu show a bit of over hang for the user to still see a bit of the drawer background when it's closed.

EDIT TO ADD: What do I mean by "**overhang**"?

> In the Google example below, the white app drawer is present at the bottom, it never fully disappears. A piece of it hangs over the content so users can see a few things on it plus a small prompt to slide it up fully. I’d like my own slider to not fully disappear but leave some pixels of overhang.

Here is the code I am successfully using for the drawer:

```js
$(function () {
  $("a.toggle").click(function () {
 $(".menu-container").toggle("slide", {direction:'right'}, 500);
 $(this).toggleClass("open");
  });

  $(".main-navigation ul li a").click(function () {
 $(".menu-container").toggle("slide", {direction:'left'}, 350);
 $("a.toggle").toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

```css
.menu-container {
   position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 999em;
    background: rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.85);
    display:none;
}
.menu-container ul{padding:2em;}
.toggle{
  background:red;
  color:#fff;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:1em;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position:absolute;
  z-index:999;
  top:50%;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<a class="toggle">Menu</a>
<div class="menu-container">
<ul>
<li>Menu Item 1</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here's how I actually want it to function (I am showing Google Maps mobile drawer as an example):

- The white drawer at the bottom has a few settings links
- The little grey tictac on the white drawer lets you swipe the container up to take up the whole screen
- Is it possible for the jQuery container I'm toggle sliding in and out to have a bit of overhang like this, for users to see even when closed?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by an overhang?

Comment: Great question — it’s hard to describe what to call that. The white app drawer is present at the bottom, it never fully disappears. A piece of it hangs over the content so users can see a few things on it plus a small prompt to slide it up fully. I’d like my own slider to not fully disappear but leave some pixels of overhang (which I will style similarly to the google one)

Comment: maybe we'd call it a 'tab' or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in 10 different ways - but it all depends on your situation. It's always a little bit of a juggling act. - but check out translate. That's what I'd use.

```js
var thing = document.querySelector('[rel="clicky-thing"]');

thing.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
 event.target.classList.toggle('open');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 1rem;
  min-height: 400px; /* arbitrary */
  /* */
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* */
  transition: .2s;
  transform: translateY(-200px);
}

.menu:not(.open) {
  transform: translateY(-50px);
}
```

```html
<nav class='menu' rel='clicky-thing'>
  this is a menu... and it would have stuff in it
</nav>
```

example with button: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/zwq2okev/

Comment: Great solution, and I appreciate you renaming it a tab. My tired brain could not get there last night. Cheers!

Comment: You can use the same idea for menus with no visible tab. : )

Comment: The only issue with this solution: the second any item inside .menu is written in a tag like <p>, <span> etc (for the label MENU I intend to add) the drawer cannot open because the class "open" is added to it. I need to target the .open class on ONLY .menu/clicky-thing. I'm too much of a javascript novice to know how :)

Comment: And fixed it! Researched til I understood I could use document.getElementbyID and toggle classlist on it that way. event.target targets all descendants and I just couldn't get stopPropagation to work (I'm probably to green to understand how that works anyways). Cheers!

Comment: There are many ways that have their pros and cons. Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/zwq2okev/ of using a button (which is probably the right way to go) - and then if you have client-side routing... you could also attach that function to the link's event. : )

Comment: You can also look into touch gestures for this type of thing.

Comment: You were so helpful and I really thank you for putting me on the right road here. I am learning how to really write my own javascript/jQuery tasks instead of just copying snippets of existing functions. Thank you for helping me learn!~

Comment: @RonnieDyer Join us in the CSS Discord: https://discord.gg/pFc6XmH